# Does Apache Camel replace or complement creating micro-services with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, microservices

I have been working for a while with Spring micro-services and have no come across Apache Camel as a tool for building micro-services.  I'm unclear -- is Apache Camel a replacement for creating micro-sevices with Spring Boot or does it add functionality / short-cuts to developing such services with Spring Boot?  It's already fairly simple to create microservices with Spring Boot so it's hard to imagine what Apache Camel would add but that is the essence of my question.

Comment: Apache Camel is an integration framework, probably best comparable with Spring integration. You can use it if you need to integrate data from multiple sources and process certain tasks. You can either combine it with Spring Boot or expose own HTTP services either directly via Tomcat/Jetty/Netty/Undertow/... integration or simply use Camel's RestDSL (which unfortunately has not much to do with REST other than exposing a HTTP endpoint for certain HTTP methods). A pro for Camel is probably its [huge number of supported components](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components)

Answer (score 2):

Apache Camel has nothing to do with microservices.

It's an implementation of the Enterprise Integration Patterns: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Apache Camel provides an implementation for most of the patterns from the book from Gregor Hohpe and Bobby Woolf. Plus a variety of inbound and outbound endpoints to integrate with systems like the file system, FTP, HTTP, Messaging, Facebook etc.

Find more information on the website: https://camel.apache.org/

There is a Spring Boot Starter project to run Camel in a Spring Boot application:
https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/4.0.x/index.html

Comment: "has nothing to do with microservices" is a little harsh, maybe? You can certainly use Camel in something deployed as a microservice. So to OP, you can use Camel to handle the data/message routing/transformation in your microservice that also uses Spring Boot.

Comment: @SteveHuston using Camel to create Microservices with no integration aspect is ridiculous. If it is a plain Microservice plain old springboot will give you much more freedom. Camel is a EIP toolkit and while it might be hammer not everything is a nail.

Comment: @Namphibian - excellent points, certainly. Good clarification. But the original question was so high level it's hard to say what the situation really is. I leave it to the OP to figure out if Camel's addition brings any value.

Comment: The third link is no longer working.

Comment: @MehdiCharife fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

> what Apache Camel would add, that is the essence of my question

In service of declaring REST based microservices, Camel's REST DSL provides a fluent API for declaring microservices. Take for example:

```
rest("/books").produces("application/json")
    .get().outType(Book[].class)
        .to("bean:bookService?method=getBooks(${header.bookCategory})")
```

Should tell you at a glance that requests to the path /books will get you a List of Book, as long as you send a request parameter named bookCategory. This is mapped to a POJO bean called bookService.

Comment: What would happen after the request is sent to the service? Will camel forward the result of the specified method to the client that made the request to the path `/books`?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is a framework which simplifies application packing and startup while Spring is the actual framework which has libraries for performing various tasks.
Technically, we can use Camel for building micro-services as well and many aspects of camel depend on Spring. If you foresee many integration related functionality like sending email or communicating with other system, you can use also use Hexagonal architecture.